# jquery .submit() validate problem

Tags: jquery, validation

So this validation thing I wrote works but for some reason I need to click twice for the form to submit. Any ideas?

```
        $('#signup').submit(function() {
        console.log('Clicked');
    $('#signup').validate({
            rules: {
    FNAME: {
        required: true,
        notPlaceholder: true
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        notPlaceholder: true,
        email: true
    }
},
        errorLabelContainer: "div.error",
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.colorbox({width:"300px", href:'thankyou.html'});
            $('#signup').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

thanks

Comment: Is strange because the console log outputs something when you click it the first time...

Comment: Move the $('#signup').validate call outside of the submit handler and put in document.ready handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$('#signup').validate` call is *inside* `$('#signup').submit`, which means the validator isn't attached until the first time the user tries to submit the form. As Cybernate pointed out in a comment, moving the `validate` call before the `submit` call will attach the validator first.

It's a little confusing; `validate` actually *sets up* validation, rather than performs it right away.

Once validation has been set up using `validate`, you can actually change your `submit` call to look like this:

```
$('#signup').submit(function() {
  return $('#signup').valid();
});
```